# Calling a new form clicking an item in listbox when the listbox items change

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox

I want to create a program that when the user selects an item in a combobox

( e.g : chooses option "Category 1" )

The listbox will update with several options

( e.g : "Program1", "Program2",)

When the user selects one of the options and starts it via a button, a new form will be launched, each option has a different form and each category has options

Kindly tell me how to do this
-Thanks!

Comment: Have you even tried anything yet

Comment: [How to: Display One Form from Another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws1btzy8(v=vs.90).aspx). Only difference is you'll probably want to create a constructor which takes 1 or more arguments (based on their `ComboBox` selection, for example) and then do whatever necessary in the constructor based on that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

Let's assume you are using arrays of strings to hold the listbox values.

For example:

```
string[] category1;
string[] category2;
```

Populated with the values.. "Program1", "Program2", etc... that you want associated for each "category."

You can then, on your combo box have a SelectedIndexChanged event. Upon selecting which category you want from the combobox you can fill the listbox with the contents of the array associated with that option.

Example:

```
      private void yourComboBoxName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e) 
{
          if (yourComboBoxName.text == "category1")
                 'populate listbox with that categories options
          elseif (yourComboxName.text == "category2")
                 'populate listbox with that categories options
          end if
 }
```

Once you have the listbox populating with your correct options then its as simple as having a click event, not unlike the selectedindexchanged event on the combobox, for the button on your form to open the form associated with that option.

Example:

```
 private void yourButtonName_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

           if (yourListBoxName.text == "option1")
                 'call form to show
          elseif (yourListBoxName.text == "option2")
                'call form to show
          end if
}
```

For simplicity I used arrays and if statements for you but in reality there is a thousand ways to skin a cat. Happy coding

Comment: I understand the two last parts, could you clarify the first part about populating the arryes with values?

Comment: string[] category2 = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" }; Then you can access them by calling that location such as category2[2] = "Tue". If this answer satisfies you please mark it as answered

Comment: This Worked, huge thanks! If you don't mind answering, is there a way to add display a description in a label when an certain item is selected? So when the user selects "option1" a declared label next to it will display a description, this description being different from other options

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out.
Huge thanks man, i've been searching this for soo long!